# Freezing graphics if points are ordered

Tags: c#, comparator

I'm trying to draw a polygon by 4 dots. 
At first I took 4 dots by click and draw a polygon.
Previous version of constructor was like this:

```
public Polygon(Point a1, Point b1, Point c1, Point d1, Pen myPen)
{
    this.a = a1;
    this.b = b1;
    this.c = c1;
    this.d = d1;
    this.pen = myPen;
}
```

Then I decided to order my dots clockwise and wrote a custom comparator.

```
public Polygon(Point a1, Point b1, Point c1, Point d1, Pen myPen)
{
    List<Point> pointsOfList = new List<Point>() { a1, b1, c1, d1 };
    int averageX = Convert.ToInt32(pointsOfList.Average(arg1 => arg1.X));
    int averageY = Convert.ToInt32(pointsOfList.Average(arg2 => arg2.Y));
    pointsOfList = pointsOfList.OrderBy(m => m, new Clockwise(new Point(averageX, averageY))).ToList();
    this.a = pointsOfList[0];
    this.b = pointsOfList[1];
    this.c = pointsOfList[2];
    this.d = pointsOfList[3];
    this.pen = myPen;
}
public class Clockwise : IComparer<Point>
{
    public Point refPoint { get; set; }
    public Clockwise(Point inpPoint)
    {
        refPoint = inpPoint;
    }

    public int Compare(Point pointA, Point pointB)
    {
        //  Variables to Store the atans
        double aTanA, aTanB;

        //  Fetch the atans
        aTanA = Math.Atan2(pointA.Y - refPoint.Y, pointA.X - refPoint.X);
        aTanB = Math.Atan2(pointB.Y - refPoint.Y, pointB.X - refPoint.X);

        //  Determine next point in Clockwise rotation
        if (aTanA < aTanB) return 1;
        else if (aTanB < aTanA) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

After that my program starts freezing. I click the dots for polygon, application takes 100% of CPU usage and nothing happens. If I get back to the previous constructor without order - everything is fine. If I track program in Debug Mode, everything is fine too.

Comment: Is it possible to break into debugger once the app freezes? Maybe attach to process, in menu Debug > Attach to Process.

Comment: Yes, you'll hang OrderBy() when your comparer doesn't produce consistent results.  And it doesn't, it can only work correctly if the points form a convex polygon and the refPoint is strictly inside the polygon.  Using Average() doesn't cut it.  And you'll have to fix the modular behavior of Math.Atan2(), adding +/-2*pi when necessary, that's the one that causes the hang.

Comment: @HansPassant Currently I'm working only with convex polygons. How can I fix Math.Atan2() behaviour?

Comment: The most interesting part, I've just added logging to the file and everything works fine. All logs are clear and process doesn't freeze.